# ¿se puede utilizar ajax adentro de una función de xmlhttprequest?

Tags: javascript, php

Tengo una función en una archivo `javascript` externo que se ejecuta mediante `window.onload()`
bueno en esta función obtengo unas variables que se encuentran en el `localStorage` y quisiera aprovechar ya que tengo estas variables para hacer una consulta a mysql y por lo que he consultado debo utilizar ajax para poder realizarla y que me obtenga los datos encontrados para después mostrarlos en el `html`.

La estructura de la función en donde esta el `XMLHttpRequest()` es:

```
function cargarDatos() {
   let aux = localStorage.getItem("clave");
   const xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
   xhttp.open('GET',aux,true);
   xhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
      var resI = "", resJ = "";
      if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
         var datos = JSON.parse(this.response);
         let nomPROD = localStorage.getItem("nombrePROD");
         let categ = localStorage.getItem("categoria");
         let subcateg = localStorage.getItem("subcategoria");
         //Realizó lecturas de archivo JSON
      } 
   }
   xhttp.send(); 
}
```

Quisiera realizar la consulta con ajax antes de cerrar la sentencia if relacionada con el estado y el status del `XMLHttpRequest()` y utilizar las variables `categ, subcateg` como parametros de la busqueda, ¿esto es posible y permitido? por lo pronto estoy estructurando el archivo para la busqueda en php.

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` es una petición AJAX y, sí, puedes hacer otra petición donde tienes el comentario `//Realizó lecturas de archivo JSON`, aunque te recomiendo cambiar a la [API fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch), que es más simple e intuitiva.

Comment: Al parecer todo lo que necesitas se encuentra en localStorage, entonces, ¿por qué quieres hacer dos peticiones Ajax? ¿No es mejor recoger todo lo que necesites y luego hacer una sola petición?

Comment: Una es para leer un archivo ``JSON`` (el cuál ya lo tengo completo) y la otra petición la quiero para leer una base de datos; En sí el argumento de la busqueda  ya la estoy mandando por un script para poder utilizarla en ``php`` y espero obtener un arreglo de los resultados e imprimirlos con el ``innerHTML``.